# Not able to access file in oracle database (no permition or file error)

Tags: oracle

Hi guys i am not able to solve this issue

i am trying to add clob to file but i cannot access the file (windows user)

i created directory

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY oraclovsky AS 'C:\Users\...\xmlSubory';
```

i granded access using

GRANT ALL ON DIRECTORY ORACLOVSKY TO admin;

i controlled path by trying to create file by

```
spool C:\Users\...\xmlSubory\myfile.txt;--...was just too long
```

that worked
so i am guessing the path is right and i have that file there
BUT

```
declare
cob xmltype;
begin

select
   sys_nc_rowinfo$
    into cob
       from osoba_xml
       where rownum=1;
dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(cob.getclobval(), 'ORACLOVSKY', 'testfile2.txt');
end;
/
```

i am still getting file not exist or no permitions error i tried other ways to write data still same error

*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
operating system.

*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
and if reading, verify that the file exists.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please make sure that the xmlSubory directory exists in the **Oracle server**.
- Please make sure that Oracle user has read and write rights on xmlSubory directory in **oracle server**.

**Please note that** the `SPOOL` command creates files in the client machine and **Oracle directories refer to Oracle server folder/directory.**

Comment: thx man i thought i am accessing data from pc dir so thx a lot i was stuck for few hours

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, then you can mark it as accepted so that your question is marked as resolved.